# Twig - Looping through tweet text from twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, twig, twitter-oauth

I am using [Abraham's TwitterOAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) along with Twig to build a mini app where users authorize then search for tweets based on their input.

I can successfully dump the return from the API to my page, but when I try to isolate just the tweet text for each tweet returned I'm having no luck.

Here's the relevant code for my dashboard.php file:

```
$user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

if(isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $statuses = $connection->get("search/tweets", array("q" => "$query"));
    echo $twig->render("dashboard.html", array("access_token" => $access_token, "user" => $user, "statuses" => $statuses));
  } else {
    echo $twig->render("dashboard.html", array("access_token" => $access_token, "user" => $user));    
  }
```

And then **the problem code** in my twig template:

```
{% if statuses %}
<ul>
  {% for status in statuses %}
  <li>{{ statuses.text|e }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{{ dump(statuses) }}
{% endif %}
```

The {{ dump(statuses) }} works, but nothing is spit out inside the UL. I'm very new to all of this, so I've just been looking at Abraham's example code [here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth-demo/blob/master/templates/profile.html), where he does this:

```
{% if user.status %}
    {{ user.status.text }}
{% else %}
    {{ user.description }}
{% endif %}
```

So I figured I could do the same thing, but it's not working for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out by comparing the example responses from the [GET account/verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) (the request being sent out in Abraham's user code) and the [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets).

If you compare the beginnings of the responses, you will notice that there is an extra level to traverse with the search/tweets response.

So instead of doing:

```
{% for status in statuses %}
  <li>{{ statuses.text|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I did:

```
{% for status in statuses.statuses %}
  <li>{{ statuses.text|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I realize the naming there isn't great, but to break it down for any other newbs like me: the first "statuses" is the variable I sent to twig, the second "statuses" is from the response I'm getting from the API.

In my original code there was nothing to loop through because I hadn't gone far enough down to reach the information about the individual tweets, I was basically trying to loop through the parent.